# Saving a .txt through a loop issue

Tags: python

I have list of big .txt files. To save them, I am making a for loop, but the problem is that the final text is cutted when it is saved(it is not the full file), I assume, because Python is moving too fast and don't have time to save everything, because when I try to print the text on the console it is in the script, just not saving. I have added `time.sleep()`, and with 3 or 5 sec everything is saved in the txt, but I was wondering for better way, something like "wait until", to wait the saving. Because I am not sure on a different computers what time will take, or with different .txt files.Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
Text=[Text1, Text2, Text3, Text4]
index=0
for x in List_Of_Names:
    Name=str(List_Of_Names[index])

    file=open('Texts\\'+Product+'_'+ Name  + '.txt', 'w')
    file.write(Texts[index])
    file.close
    time.sleep(5)

    index+=1

time.sleep(5)

print('The new .txt files were saved in ' + Location +"\\Scenes"  )

print('\n')

print('Press "Enter" to escape.')

wait=sys.stdin.readline()
```

Comment: Is that your actual code? There are plenty of issues with variable names there. As for Python "going too fast", that's not possible

Comment: note you aren't actually closing the file here, change file.close to read 'file.close()'.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are re-writing the content of your text with each iteration.

Try:

```
with open('Texts\\'+Product+'_'+ Name  + '.txt', "w") as infile:
    for x in List_Of_Names:
        ViewName=str(List_Of_Names[index])

    infile.write(Texts[index])
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `with` for opening the file as:-

```
with open('Texts\\'+Product+'_'+ Name  + '.txt', 'w') as fd:
    fd.write(Texts[index])
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion but doesn't actually answer the question right?